# Is facebook connect what I need?

Tags: facebook

Would facebook connect allow FB friends to have direct access to a wordpress site whereas others would need userID and password?

Comment: FB friends of the user using FB connect? or YOUR friends who have FB and plan to use connect?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. Any facebook user would see a "connect with facebook" button or similar. Clicking on the button would explain what permissions the wordpress site requires (in this case, public profile info and maybe the list of friends if you wish to restrict access only to friends of a certain person). Accepting would authenticate the user with the wordpress site without asking for an user identifier or password.